# How do you nest list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been assigned homework and have spent hours running in circles attempting to nest comprehensions. Specifically, I am attempting to find vowels in a string (say, S = 'This is an easy assignment') and have it return the vowels from the string in a list (so, [1], [1], [1], [2], [3])

I figured out quickly [len(x) for x in S.lower().split()]
to give the length of the words, but cannot successfully get it to produce the required output. This problem cannot use anything but list comprehensions.

Comment: You're trying to count the vowels in each word?

Comment: For general purpose counting, you can use `collections.Counter(S)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
[[len([v for v in x if v in 'aeiou'])] for x in S.lower().split()]
```

Not sure why you'd want the counts to be single element lists themselves, but that would do it with only list comprehensions (plus a `len` call).

Note: A suggested edit was to use `[sum(x.count(v) for v in 'aeiou') for x in S.lower().split()]`; this is a reasonable way to do it (though `x.count` would mean traversing the string five times; in CPython it might still be faster, but in JIT-ed interpreters a single pass is likely superior), and to keep it use list comprehensions, not generator expressions, you'd have to pointlessly realize the list before summing: `[sum([x.count(v) for v in 'aeiou']) for x in S.lower().split()]`